# PHP, "The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator." error when submitting

Tags: php

I made an HTML form that retrieves data from a mysql database via a php code in a separate file. So far so god, everything works fine. Then after the user edits the data in that form it submits it via another php page and the data are written back to the database.
This used to work fine until last spring, where many users complanied "The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator." error. What might be causing this? Is it my code? It seems to happen only from those that use chrome. In the console I get no errors. Could you please help me?

Comment: Is the URL https or http?

Comment: Does it work on other web browsers apart from Chrome?

Comment: 1. Make sure its not a browser issue, if it works with another browser then chrome might be the issue. Try different browsers, maybe from different networks (work / public (from you own home)) too. It also might be a caching problem, try clearing cookies and/or reinstalling chrome again. 2. [What have you researched so far?](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+requested+URL+was+rejected.+Please+consult+with+your+administrator.) Make sure to mention what you tried already. 3. Check your logs. For that you need to know the time that happend.

Comment: 4. Make sure that the problem can be produced whenever you want. If it only happens to your clients then its really hard for you to debug that. Once you have (done) all that make sure you update your question with everything you think might be relevent.

Comment: It is an HTTPS URL. I can reproduce it with Chrome. Firefox has no problems with it. I have cleared the cookies from Chrome and it still does the same thing.
Something I noticed is:
1. With all cookies cleaned, I load the page which by reading the data creates a cookie.
2. If I manually delete that cookie now that the page has been loaded, then the data is submitted as expected and I do not get that error.
It is very strange. The logs of Apache do not shed any light to it. What else should I look for? My setup is with Apache and PHP on Windows Server.

Answer (score 1):

My IT fixed the problem. Here is their response for the history:
something from the code of the request is violating HTTP Protocol with the message "Number of headers 21 exceeded maximum limit of: 20" which caused the Web Application Firewall to block the request. We have now increased the maximum number of headers allowed to 25 but you should also check your code to adhere to HTTP Protocol standards and security best practices.

A ton of thanks to you all for helping me out.
Best,